# Using Firebase's FCM token to ban a user?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

I'm building an app using Ionic, Angular, and Firebase.

I'd like to have the option to ban users if needs be, I'm wondering if storing the user's FCM token in my database under the `ban-list` and then checking on the client-side to see if these variables match is a good way to go about it?

I'm already getting the user's FCM token since I'm also displaying push notifications, so it seems like a pretty easy addition.

I'm building an MVP of my product so it doesn't have to be like Fort Knox, but I'm just curious if there's a better way or if the method I listed above is reasonable.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: What would you be using the instance ID token for? I get that you're storing it in a node called `ban-list`, but what do you do with the information in that list? Right now your question reads a bit like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and it's easier to help if we know what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I'd loop through the `ban-list` node and compare the tokens in there to the user's token and if they are equal I'd log the user out and show an alert... does that clear up your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the FCM token is a good parameter to use as a ban list item, why not the user uid that's generated when they sigup with firebase? Or the user doesn't have to login? Other solution (and that's not the best, but will work) if you're not using firebase auth is baning the user using device uuid that you can get using the [device plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/device/), the case about using the device uuid is that if someone else try to login the app in that device they simply can't, since you're blocking the entire device and not just one user.